# The target-entity cannot be found Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, php-7.2

My problem is that when I try to update ORM Doctrine with this command:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

I get this error:

```
In MappingException.php line 762:
The target-entity Product cannot be found in 'Bug#products'.  
orm:schema-tool:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force]
```

Code on the line 762 is:

```
{
    return new self("The target-entity " . $targetEntity . " cannot be found in '" . $sourceEntity."#".$associationName."'.");
}
```

Where is the problem? Or have some one well working tutorial of Doctrine? Because the offical one is so buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the namespace in file Bug.php there was bad path to the namespace and it throw me this error.